# Where can I find a more information for an http 500 internal server error when debugging with visual studio 2015 using iis express?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have created an Asp.Net 5.0, MVC 6 application using the empty template in Visual Studio 2015. I have the debugger set up to launch IIS express and use Chrome as the browser. In my project, I have added a Home controller, and a view for the Index action. I have also added _Layout.cshtml and _ViewStart.cshtml. I have the default code that has been automatically generated. The only changes I have made are to add and use MVC in the ConfigureServices() and Configure() methods in Startup.cs; and to list Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc as a dependency in Project.json file.

When I launch the debugger, nothing is sent to the browser even though I have a title in my index.cshtml page. When I pull up the F12 developer tools and look at the Console tab, it just says

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500
>   (Internal Server Error)

Where can I find more information about the server error?

The visual studio output window doesn't seem to have anything relevant. Is there a window in visual studio, or a log file in the OS where the actual server error is recorded? It used to be possible to debug the application_error handler in global asax file, which doesn't appear to be available in AspNet 5.0. Is there something similar to application_error?

I have looked at the IIS express trace log file. It says

> ModuleName httpPlatformHandler
>
> Notification EXECUTE_REQUEST_HANDLER
>
> HttpStatus 500
>
> HttpReason Internal Server Error
>
> HttpSubStatus 0
>
> ErrorCode The operation completed successfully.  (0x0)
>
> ConfigExceptionInfo

I'm asking this question because I'm interested in learning the process of identifying HTTP 500 server errors when they occur, not just fixing the particular error I have.

Comment: Run the application and set break points where you are expecting the execution path to go.

Comment: You should probably start with http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/diagnostics.html

Comment: In your F12 tool, open the network tab and select play to start recording network traffic. Then navigate to the location causing the error. You should see a http 500 response, double click on the 500 error. I bet there will be a lot more detail bout the error within. If proper logging is setup you might find detailed information in the windows event log under the applications list view.

Comment: Add a breakpoint to your Controller. If the breakpoint is not hit, then there is a problem on your configuration. Provide your Startup.cs code please

Comment: The best lead so far is the diagnostics link. Thanks Alex. The stack trace that appears on the developer exception page is very helpful.

Comment: Enclose the code that generates the error in a Try Catch block with a sErr string variable set to the exception message (ex.Message) in the Catch section. Examine the exception message when the server error is generated in debug. This should describe what caused the server error.

Comment: I have put breakpoints in all my methods in the startup, and homecontroller classes and they all get hit. I have wrapped all my code blocks in try-catch and no exceptions are being thrown while my code is executing. The server errors must be coming from code that is running in another thread. I tried app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage() which provides a stacktrace that has helped identify some of the server errors in development. The app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error"); appears to be calling a home controller action method called Error(). Not sure how determine the server error from here.

Comment: The errors can come before or after your app in the pipeline, for example depending on your auth method some files can't be served if the program/user accessing the web server doesn't have read access on the filesystem - if you run VS as a user (recommended) and not administrator this often comes up.